# IndexedDB behaviour and updating browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, microsoft-edge, indexeddb

I was wondering if anyone knows how the IndexedDB reacts when the browsers update, is there a posibility that the information stored in it can be affected or erased in some way? I did a general research on the matter, but I see there's a lack of information regarding browsers updating.

This question is focused for the general browsers that fully or partially supports IndexedDB like Chrome, FireFox, Edge and IE.

Answer (score 0):

If the user's data was lost or corrupted, it would be a critical bug on the part of the browser.

Other than potential bug reports, you're unlikely to find any documentation since it should be a non-issue.

Comment: I thought about the same, and given the lack of information a bugs regarding this issue, it just reafirms what you say. I just wanted to go on the safe side and try and get some feedback